# Finding out goal state from n! different permutations without any extra information efficiently

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Is there a way of finding out goal state from n! different permutations if i dont have any extra information.

The problem i am facing is that i have n objects that are identical and one of there permutation is my goal state. So i want to know is there is any way that i cam do it better than using the brute force approach.

Thanks

Comment: If all objects are identical, all permutations are also identical! There must be a way to differentiate the objects... and if you can differentiate between permutations, you can differentiate between objects!

Comment: Are you saying that you have a test you can perform which you feed a permutation in, and it tells you either "yes, that is your goal" or else "no, that is not your goal"? And you know nothing else -- you don't know what computations the test performs, or what its criteria are, or how close your input is to correct? If so then all you can do is an exhaustive search.

Comment: Yes @SteveJessop actually this is the case....

Comment: @Abdul - You'll only be able to do better than an exhaustive search if there is a characteristic of the goal state that you are able to make use of.

Comment: And note that the answer doesn't depend in any way on the fact that the candidate solutions happen to be permutations. You have `N` (which happens to equal `n!`) inputs, one of which produces the output you want, and the only way to determine which is to check them one at a time (or anyway one at a time per thread of execution) until you find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you have function like f: permutation->bool that has only one true value and you know nothing more about it? I believe what you are facing is indeed brute force.

It's like finding the null of a black box function. Guess the number I'm thinking of without any hints. You have to say anyone of them.